# Cordova firebase Analytics not shown anything

Tags: cordova, firebase, jquery-mobile, google-analytics, cordova-plugins

I have Cordova 6.4.0 and JQuery mobile framework.

I installed the firebase and setup all the config and check it many times.

Some features are working such as (setBade,getToken) but the live Analytics and logEvent not working.

I checked the XCode debug and no error at all from firebase side.

I included the .info list, added the adSupport framework, I added these line in native code also:

`#import "Firebase.h"`
`[FIRApp configure];`

And still same issue

Here is my javascript codes:

```

```
 window.FirebasePlugin.subscribe("testing");

       window.FirebasePlugin.logEvent("page_view", {page: "initiator"});


      window.FirebasePlugin.grantPermission();

      window.FirebasePlugin.logEvent("cordova", {content_type: "page_view", item_id: "cordova"});

      window.FirebasePlugin.setBadgeNumber(100);


      window.FirebasePlugin.getToken(function(token) {
            // save this server-side and use it to push notifications to this device
            console.log("Firebase ===>"+token);
        }, function(error) {
            console.error("Firebase ===> failed"+error);
        });
```

```

^^ it's all on DeviceReady event

Here is some XCode showing all success:

`2017-06-15 15:44:43.626 Ajeer-Client[712] <Notice> [Firebase/Crash][I-CRA000004] Successfully initialized
2017-06-15 15:44:43.731 Ajeer-Client[712] <Notice> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Firebase Analytics v.3700000 started
2017-06-15 15:44:43.731 Ajeer-Client[712] <Notice> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see xxxxx)
2017-06-15 15:44:45.094 Ajeer-Client[712] <Notice> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023012] Firebase Analytics enabled`

So what's next !! Do I need to upload the app to production in order to get the traffic?

Comment: Have you found any solution? I'm facing same issue.